# Window freezes for one time when String is drawn

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

While I was making a 2D Game in Java, a (atleast to me) very strange problem occured. I've provided a **runnable, shortened example** which reproduces my problem. When the **x-coordinate** of the red square is between **100** and **120** it should **draw the string** "Sample Text" above the square. However, you will see if you run the code, the window **freezes** completely for a few seconds. After the lag you can go over the area without problems, and the text will be shown. This problem only occurs when the program draws a String above the square. If I change the code so only another square appears above the red one, there's no lag. (I commented that in my code)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;


public class MyExample extends JApplet {

    int x = 10;
    int y = 150;

    public void init() {

        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        Action right = new moveRight();
        Action left = new moveLeft();
        JRootPane rootPane = getRootPane();
        rootPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right");
        rootPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left");
        rootPane.getActionMap().put("right", right);
        rootPane.getActionMap().put("left", left);
        getContentPane().add(new Paint());
    }

    protected class moveRight extends AbstractAction {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x+=3;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    protected class moveLeft extends AbstractAction {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x-=3;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    class Paint extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(x,y,10,10);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(100,100,100,200);
            g.drawLine(129,100,129,200);
            if(x>100&&x<120) {
                g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString("Sample Text",x-30,y-25);
                //g.fillRect(x,y-15,10,10); - This work fine if you remove the g.setFont and the drawString
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried to draw it outside of your if?

Comment: hmm, if it works outside your if with the exact same code and other code does works inside your "if" i cant think of whats causing the problem to trigger

Comment: sorry for not being able to do alot but ill be researching about this

Comment: um, try changing your if to "if(x=100)"
if what i read is correct it means that the program keeps drawing infinitely

Comment: ah, i meant it as a test only to check if thats what triggers the error

Comment: well then my last idea is to set the new font before the if, sorry for not being of much help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that you are trying to load the font within the `paintComponent` method AND the underlying API trying to load the font and it's details before it can paint them.

I did think you could just pre-cache the font using something like...

```
class Paint extends JPanel {

    private Font paintFont;

    public Paint() {
        paintFont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 15);
        setFont(paintFont);
    }
```

But in my testing, this still didn't work, what I actually ended up doing was adding a call to `getFontMetrics`, which seems to force the API to load the font and it's properties into memory, making it render immediately, for example

```
class Paint extends JPanel {

    private Font paintFont;

    public Paint() {
        paintFont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 15);
        setFont(paintFont);
        getFontMetrics(paintFont);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(100, 100, 100, 200);
        g.drawLine(129, 100, 129, 200);
        if (x > 100 && x < 120) {
            System.out.println("...");
            //g.setFont(paintFont);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString("Sample Text", x - 30, y - 25);
            //g.fillRect(x,y-15,10,10); - This work fine if you remove the g.setFont and the drawString
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this will make your application load slightly slower, but will allow it to run faster as you've moved the loading of the font out of the paint cycle

Answer (score 3):

On my system `TimesRoman` doesn't exist.

I used `Times New Roman` with no problems. I also tried a few other fonts and they worked no problem. So I guess specifying an invalid font name causes a hiccup?

I also created the font once and cached it:

```
Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15);
```

and then in the painting method used:

```
g.setFont( font );
```

Also, don't forget the `super.paintComponent(g);`

This question contains the code I used to list the fonts on my machine: [Java JTextArea font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370459/java-jtextarea-font/5371008#5371008)

Comment: `Just the caching mentioned in @camickr 's answer...` - actually my suggestion was to use the proper font family name. Did you run the font program I provided to you? Does "TimesRoman" appear in the font list (it doesn't for me)? I must admit I don't know what the difference is between the two fonts. When I print the two side by side they look the same to me. So my question to you is how do you know you are getting "TimesRoman" and not "Times New Roman"? So I would suggest you use the font family name that Java knows about.